# If a language is regular then every subset of this language is regular?

Tags: formal-languages

anyone can explain this ...

If a language is regular then every subset of this language is regular? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is obviously false, since any language is a subset of the Kleene star of its alphabet, which is trivially regular.